# Using PHP to Get a String Between Two Strings

Tags: php

Name 
 Address 
 Pincode 
 Phone Number

I have to get Name,address,pincode,phone number as a variable

```
<span>Name <br> Address <br> Pincode <br> Phone Number</span>
```

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read how to ask an
 [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and the 
 [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)
 and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)
 and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [TAKE THE TOUR](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: trim `<span>` from start&end and explode by <br> and then use `list()` to make the explodes variables

Comment: can you please send me the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use preg split,

```
$string = '<span>Name <br> Address <br> Pincode <br> Phone Number</span>';
$array = preg_split('/(\s*<[^>]+>\s*)/', $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
var_dump($array);
```

Output

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "Name"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Address"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Pincode"
  [3]=>
  string(12) "Phone Number"
}
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/805a0e519a3b8069c68220462752a1cae98ea57a)

The regular expression is a pretty basic one that matches any tag. Match `<` then match anything but the `>` as many times as possible then match the closing `>`.  So it will match anything that is `<{somthing}>`.

Then if you want them as actual variables you can do this (if the format/order is always the same)

```
list($name,$address,$pincode,$phonenumber) = $array;
echo $name; //outputs "Name"
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a4de5168b7d19e2ba98852013b8671692aadb3f)

P.S - you may or may not wan't `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` it removes any empty array elements that resulted from the split.  If you don't use it you don't need the 3rd argument (-1) which is the number of matches to do, that just has to be `-1` or `0`(If I remember right) so you can get to the 4th argument.

Comment: var_dump($array[0]);

Comment: this is the first array but we get string(4) "Name" this

Comment: i need to get only name

Comment: no "" no string

Comment: I don't know what any of that means ^

Comment: thanks you tell the answer

Comment: Ok, glad I could help.